# throwing exception SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, raspberry-pi

My raspberry pi is connected to microcontroller over serial pin. I am trying to read the data from the serial port. The script reads the data for few seconds. However, it terminates throwing following exception

serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)

I have used following python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200, timeout=.5)

while 1:

       response = serialport.readlines(None)
       print response 
       time.sleep(.05)


serialport.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you should be using if you are seriously trying to just transfer and print a file:

```
for line in serialport.readlines().split('\n'):
    print line
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------

I believe you are having problems because you are using readlines(None) instead of readline()  Readline() reads it a line at a time, and will wait for each one.  If reading a whole file it will be slower than readlines.  But readlines() expects a whole file all at once.  It is obviously not waiting for your serial transfer speed.

### --------------------------------------------------

My data-logging loop receives a line every two minutes and writes it to a file.  It could easily just print each line like you show in the OP.
readine() waits for each line.  I have tested it to wait up to 30 minutes between lines with no problems by altering the program on the Nano.

```
import datetime
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)     --/dev/ACM0 is fine 

while True :
    linein = ser.readline()

    date   = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
    date   = date[:10]            
    time   = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    time   = time[:8]

    outline = date + tab + time + tab + linein

    f = open("/home/pi/python/today.dat","a")
    f.write(outline)
    f.close()
```

Maybe changing to this approach would be better for you.